# How to change string name to specific string name?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, filenames

I want Excel (or Linux command) to change the string of values.

From:

e.g. column A

```
IN_EMAIL.201_101300_180403_131131_6160_5593
```

To:

e.g. column B

```
EMAIL.201_101300_0_180403_131131616_0000_5593
```

So:

1. Remove "IN_"
2. Add "0_" after 20th character
3. Remove "_" after 33rd character
4. Add "_000" after 37th character

I've got two formulas. How can I nest them into one?

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A4;1;3;"");18;0;"0_") 
=REPLACE(REPLACE(B4;33;1;"");36;0;"_000")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I've got two formulas. How can I nest them into  one?

=REPLACE(REPLACE(A4;1;3;"");18;0;"0_")

=REPLACE(REPLACE(B4;33;1;"");36;0;"_000")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine these two formulas:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A4;1;3;"");18;0;"0_") 
=REPLACE(REPLACE(B4;33;1;"");36;0;"_000")
```

Just replace `B4` with the first formula

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A4;1;3;"");18;0;"0_");33;1;"");36;0;"_000")
```

Alternatively you could use the following formula that might be more obvious:

```
=MID(A5;4;17) & "0_" & MID(A5;21;13) & MID(A5;35;3) & "_000" & RIGHT(A5;6)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is solved,

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A11;1;3;"");18;0;"0_");33;1;"");36;0;"_000")
```